# A word to describe someone with the same taste/likes

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe someone who has the same taste/likes as you? For example, I like dogs. How can I describe all the members in a FB group that's dedicated to sharing cute dog images/videos? The closest phrase I can think of is "interest group", but that seems to have a very specific meaning and usage.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase I associate the most with this is like-minded. From the [Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/like-minded)

> like-minded, adj
>
> agreeing in opinions, goals, etc

It doesn't have the institutional connotations that you are seeking to avoid.

The [second definition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sympathies) of sympathy, same source, usually in the plural form for this usage, also rings true:

> a. Mutual understanding or feeling between people: "Like two frightened children, we sought at the same time to comfort one another, so quick was the sympathy between us" (Nicholas Meyer).
>
> b. Agreement with or support for an opinion or position: The mayor is in sympathy with the proposal.
>
> c. often sympathies A tendency to support a position or opinion: a politician of conservative sympathies.

Answer (score 1):

Kindred spirit(s): a person(or persons) who has the same opinions, feelings, and interests as you.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/kindred-spirit

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend

***common-interest friends*** ,

who are "friends that a person has and keeps in contact with because of a shared interest, hobby, activity, club, etc."
([Link](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-common-interest-friends-how-common-interest-267496))

Answer (score 0):

I like [congenial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congenial): "having the same nature, disposition, or tastes".